# Restrain sed from deleting all url whose ending are same

Tags: bash, shell, url, sed

I have a test file containing many URLs ending with '**.com**' but I don't want to remove Gmail id URL (**abc@gmail.com**) but want to remove a URL like "**youtube.com**".

**Sample input:-** How are you, watch **youtube.com** which is provided by **abc@gmail.com**.

**Desired output:-**  How are you, watch which is provided by **abc@gmail.com**

**What I am doing-->**

I am using a sed command which removes all URL ending with ".com"

---

> sed -r -i -e 's![^:space:]*.com[^:space:]*! !g'
> file

---

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment)

Comment: What about `sed 's/[[:alnum:]._~-]*\.com//' file` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternation to capture `gmail.com`:

```
sed -r -i -e 's!([^[:space:]()]*gmail\.com[^[:space:]()]*)|[^[:space:]()]*\.com[^[:space:]()]*!\1!g' file
```

`\1` puts back the value in Group 1.